# Can I generate something like a vCalendar file that adds a Task instead of a Calendar Item to Outlook (2010)?

Tags: outlook, vcalendar

At our company we use a CRM system that we built ourselves using ASP.NET. One of the functionalities is that it allows users to download vCalendar (.vcs) files for appointments they make in the CRM system so that they can easily add these same appointments to their Outlook 2010 Calendar.

Such a .vcs file will look something like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Notice the `VEVENT` on line 4.

According to [official ICM specification](http://www.imc.org/pdi/vcal-10.txt), vCalendar also supports a `VTODO` which can be used to describe tasks or todo items. Unfortunately, Outlook doesn't support `VTODO`.

All the solutions I have found while looking into this use some form of interop and direct communication with Exchange and/or the Outlook API. The first one requires access from the CRM application to our Exchange server. This is not possible for us. The second one requires us (if I'm not mistaken) to install Outlook on our web server. This is also not possible. Now that I think about it, I guess option two will also require a connection to our Exchange server.

Does anyone know of a vCalender-like approach to allow users to add tasks to Outlook 2010?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no.

Comment: In my own research I found that Outlook 2007 does not support VTODO as a format, I created one from the spec and it did not have the desired impact in Outlook. Not sure if this is the same in Outlook 2010